# fill logical matrix [r,n] with a vector [n,]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numeric vector `values` (a series in a pandas dataframe `df`).

```
idx     values

0          NaN
1            1
2            2
3          NaN
4          NaN
5           33
6           34
7           90
8          NaN
9            5
10         NaN
11          22
12          70
13         NaN
14         672
15          10
16          73
17           9
18         NaN
19          15
```

And I constructed a logical matrix of the form

```
array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1]])
```

Using the following code fetched from some answer on SO, which unfortunately can't find anymore.

```
n=len(df)
k=5
r= n-k+1
mat=np.tile([1]*k+[0]*r, r)[:-r].reshape(r,n)
```

`mat` will have shape `(r,n)` and `df['values']` will have shape `(n,)`.

What is the proper way to fill `mat` with the values in `df['values']`?

Given the previous example, my expected output would be:

```
array([[NaN, 1, 2, NaN,       ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [  0, 1, 2,NaN,NaN,    ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [  0, 0, 2,NaN,NaN,33, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ...,  672, 10, 73, 9, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ...,      10,73, 9, NaN, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ...,        73, 9, NaN, 15]])
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?
I tried with a dot product (hoping that it would behave as in matlab and replicate my vector `r` times but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nan = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame([
         nan, 1, 2, nan, nan, 33, 34, 90, 
         nan, 5, nan, 22, 70, nan, 672, 
         10, 73, 9, nan, 15], 
     columns=['values'])

n = len(df)
k = 5
r = n - k + 1

mat = np.tile([1] * k + [0] * r, r)[:-r].reshape(r, n)

mat = np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: np.where(row, df['values'], row), 1, mat)

print(mat)
```

Outputs:

```
[[ nan   1.   2.  nan  nan   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   1.   2.  nan  nan  33.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   2.  nan  nan  33.  34.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  nan  nan  33.  34.  90.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.  nan  33.  34.  90.  nan   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  33.  34.  90.  nan   5.   0.   0.   0.   0. 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  34.  90.  nan   5.  nan   0.   0.   0. 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  90.  nan   5.  nan  22.   0.   0. 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  nan   5.  nan  22.  70.   0. 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   5.  nan  22.  70.  nan 0.     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  nan  22.  70.  nan 672.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  22.  70.  nan 672.  10.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  70.  nan 672.  10.  73.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  nan 672.  10.  73.   9.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 672.  10.  73.   9.  nan   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 0.    10.  73.   9.  nan  15.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
ary=np.array([[0,1,1],[1,0,1]])
s=df['values'].values
ary1=ary.ravel().copy().astype('float')
ary1[ary1==1]=np.tile(s,len(ary))[ary1==1]

ary1.reshape(len(ary),-1)

Out[446]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [nan,  0.,  2.]])
```

Data Input :

```
df

idx     values
0          NaN
1            1
2            2
```